# Why is the speed and quality of streaming (over LAN) so different?

Tags: lan, vlc-media-player

Can someone explain why is the quality and speed of streaming over LAN (for example with **VLC** Streaming) less better than apps like **DroidCam** where it's the same principal?

I tried many times to stream my laptop camera over VLC (LAN) with different parameters (Protocols: HTTP/RTSP, Transcoding:HD/TS..) and there is always a delay and the quality of the video is bad.

On the other hand, android apps like DroidCam stream my phone camera over LAN with such a good video quality and speed.

**So my question is why this difference?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be because of many things between the different apps:
Different resolution and/or frame rate. Better compression thus smaller throughput.
The buffer size may differ.